# Renaming Animation Channels with a Script for dummies

Tags: animation, scripting, bones

[image]

Say I have a channel called:

```
pose.bones["mixamorig:LeftShoulder"].rotation_quaternion
```

But I need it to be:

```
pose.bones["mixamorig:Shoulder.L"].rotation_quaternion
```

I found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/221111/15543)
for renaming channels, however I still don't get the desired result.

> This should do the trick. Obviously, you will have to fill in the
> complete dictionary of bone name mappings.
>
> ```
> d = {"oldname1":"newname1","oldname2":"newname2", } 
> for action in bpy.data.actions:
>     #these so called action groups are the bones, ie one group contains all fcurves of one bone
>     for group in action.groups:
>         if group.name in d:
>             oldname = group.name
>             group.name = d[oldname]
>             for fcurve in group.channels:
>                 fcurve.data_path = fcurve.data_path.replace(oldname, d[oldname])
> ```

Comment: Could you please add an image as displayed in the linked question, to indicate if your action is split into groups, and perhaps your edited dictionary eg `d = {"LeftShoulder" : "Shoulder.L", "RightShoulder" : "Shoulder.R"}` etc.

Comment: Added an image and I tried that, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

**No groups.**

Going by screenshot.

- The fcurves are not split into bone groups.
- The bones have names "mixamorig:LeftShoulder" have renamed to "Shoulder.L" *ie* stripped out "mixamorig:" and then renamed.
- Reinstated bone groups to new names. (optional)

Test script:. select rig, run script in object or pose mode. (*As always back up first.*)

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object

def bonename(dp):
    #dp = fc.data_path
    if not dp.startswith("pose.bones"):
        return None
    start = dp.find('["') + 2
    end = dp.find('"]') 
    return dp[start : end]

def rename(name):
    if name.startswith("mixamorig:"):
        name = name[10:]
    if name.startswith("Left"):
        name = f"{name[4:]}.L"
    elif name.startswith("Right"):
        name = f"{name[5:]}.R"
    return name
# test        
x = 'pose.bones["mixamorig:RightShoulder"].location[0]'
print(rename(bonename(x)))

for pb in ob.pose.bones:
    pb.name = rename(pb.name)
    
action = ob.animation_data.action

for fc in action.fcurves:
    name = bonename(fc.data_path)
    if name:
        new_name = rename(name)
        fc.data_path.replace(name, new_name)
        if not fc.group:
            fc.group = (
                    action.groups.get(new_name) 
                    or
                    action.groups.new(new_name)
                    )
```

Comment: Actually, I need "mixamorig:" to stay in. Because the new bone names are "mixamorig:Shoulder.L". 
The script removes the "mixamorig:" from the channels I renamed manually, but does nothing for the channels that I didn't rename. I'll give you a new screenshot.

Comment: Basically all I need is to get rid of Left and Right after "mixamo:" and add .L at the end of the bone name. When I do this manually the channel works correctly. I just thought there ought to be a way to script this.

Answer (score 0):

My brain was too smooth for the pyscript above (I'm sure it works but in the 30 seconds I attempted to type it in I got confused) so I found out how to do it the caveman way.

[image: Initial pose.bones error]

In the image above the channels/bones are incorrectly named. At this point, I had chosen another action (T_Pose) and selected the next action

[image: Batch Rename]

I first rename the bones back to mixamorig so the bones are correctly named. When the error disappears, I rename them back to Terrific. This then changes the rest of the channel names to what the new name should be.

[image: Completed change]

In your case, you could batch rename "mixamorig:LeftShoulder" to "mixamorig:Shoulder.L" for each action you have. You just have to rename the bones back to the original when you switch actions (this will still take a while if you have a lot of actions, I only had 8).